nftables restrict access between date and time
Documentation of nftables about match concept is too weak .
nftables document
I want accept all traffic from ip x.w.y.z with port 80 only between two Date & Time for example :
start : 2024/01/12 22:55
end   : 2024/01/15 17:30
How to do it with nftables ?

It is possible to match a packet based on date and time since kernel 5.4 (the kernel commit was in 2019).
It is done like this:
nft insert rule inet filter input handle XX ip saddr x.x.x.x tcp dport 80 \
time \> \"2024-01-12 22:55\" \
time \< \"2024-01-15 17:30\" counter log prefix \"[nft time rule] \" accept

You may find  taking care of such rules easier by placing them in a dedicated chain like so:
chain maintenance_time {
        meta time < "2024-01-12 22:55:00" counter drop comment "too early"
        meta time > "2024-01-15 17:30:00" counter drop comment "too late"
        counter accept
}

    chain input {
        ip saddr x.x.x.x tcp dport 80 counter jump maintenance_time
        ip saddr z.z.z.z tcp dport 443 counter jump maintenance_time
}

I found the information and links here useful:
How do you filter packets differently based on time of day in nftables?
